# Grouping form errors in Play! Framework

Tags: playframework

Is there an easy way to group form errors at the top of the form, rather than above each field?

Here is my Scala template:

```
@(registrationForm: Form[User])

@implicitField = @{ FieldConstructor(views.html.helper.twitterBootstrap2.twitterBootstrap2FieldConstructor.f) }

@import helper._

@helper.form(action = routes.Registration.index) {

    <fieldset>

        @if(registrationForm.hasGlobalErrors) { 
            <div class="alert alert-error">
            <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
                @registrationForm.globalError.message
            </div>
        }

        <legend>Register</legend>

        @inputText(
            registrationForm("firstName"),
            '_label -> "First Name",
            '_showConstraints -> false,
            '_showErrors -> true,
            '_error -> registrationForm.error("firstName")
        )

        @inputText(
            registrationForm("lastName"),
            '_label -> "Last Name",
            '_showConstraints -> false,
            '_showErrors -> true,
            '_error -> registrationForm.error("lastName")
        )

        @inputText(
            registrationForm("emailAddress"),
            '_label -> "Email Address",
            '_showConstraints -> false,
            '_showErrors -> true,
            '_error -> registrationForm.error("emailAddress")
        )

        @inputPassword(
            registrationForm("password"),
            '_label -> "Password",
            '_showConstraints -> false,
            '_showErrors -> true,
            '_error -> registrationForm.error("password")
        )

        @inputPassword(
            registrationForm("password"),
            '_label -> "Confirm Password",
            '_showConstraints -> false,
            '_showErrors -> true,
            '_error -> registrationForm.error("password")
        )

    </fieldset>

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Register</button>

}
```

I have a custom validation that I'm doing to check for unique email address and based on that validation, I add an error to the global errors. I'd like to have any additional errors (that are thrown as a result of validation of other fields) grouped together with this error at the top of the form. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `@if(registrationForm.hasGlobalErrors){` you could always try calling `registrationForm.globalErrors` to get the List of all errors, traverse it, and output the message for each?

example:

```
@if(registrationForm.hasGlobalErrors){
    <div class="alert alert-error">
         @for(validationError <- registrationForm.globalErrors){
              <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
              @validationError.message
         }
    </div>
}
```

EDIT: At the request from the comments below I'm updating my answer to include an alternative method for grouping custom validation messages, which may not be the "best" solution but should accomplish just that.

In your controller:

```
if(filledForm.hasErrors()){

       for(String key : filledForm.errors().keySet()){
           List<ValidationError> currentError = filledForm.errors().get(key);
           for(ValidationError error : currentError){
               flash(key, error.message());
           }
       }
}
```

Or you could use an iterator, whichever you prefer.

And then in your view something along the lines of:

```
@if(flash.size() > 0){
    <div class="alert-alert error">
        @for((key, value) <- flash){
            <strong>Error : </strong> @value<br />
        }
    </div>
}
```

Like I mentioned, not the most elegant solution, but it should get a big list of your errors at the top of your page.

Comment: The errors I'm trying to group don't seem to be getting put into the global errors. Here's what I get if I bind the request to an instance of the form...

    Form(of=class models.User, data={lastName=User, emailAddress=test@example.com, firstName=Test, password=}, value=None, errors={password=[ValidationError(password,error.required,[])]})

Comment: Sorry, I thought I read that you already had the errors added to your Global Errors. I suppose another means would be when doing your custom validation you can always add the errors to the Flash scope in your controller and then check the Flash in your View and output all ValidationErrors that you've added with their appropriate message. If that seems like the route you would like to go I can edit my answer to reflect this, though I'm not certain this is the "most correct" means.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm actually new to Play! framework; however, I've used other frameworks where it was fairly trivial to group errors at the top of the form, so I was curious if I was just missing something. If you have a solution you've used, I'd greatly appreciate it if you'd put it in your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have had also problems adding custom global errors to globalErrors and displaying them on the view.
My solution is use the errors object and add these global error under "global" key. Then in the view I display all "global" errors at the top.

My view:

```
@for(error <- form("global").errors) {
       <p>@error.message</p>
}
```

My controller:

```
ValidationError error = new ValidationError("global", "User is not authorized.");
List<ValidationError> errors = new ArrayList<ValidationError>();
errors.add(error);
loginForm.errors().put("global", errors);
return badRequest(login.render(loginForm));
```